# AUCTeX detecting modified files using different output directory

Tags: emacs, auctex

I'm using AUCTeX in Emacs, and would like to store all output files (.aux, .log, .pdf etc) in a sub-directory "output" rather than directly in the current working directory.

To achieve this, I have updated the AUCTeX settings so that the "LaTeX" command now includes `--output-directory=output` and the BibTeX and View commands open `output/%s` etc.

This works, in the sense that all intermediate files are generated in ./output correctly.

**However**, previously pressing <kbd>C-c C-c</kbd> several times would run LaTeX, then LaTeX then View, noticing after the second LaTeX run that nothing more is needed and the PDF file is ready to view (presumably it checks after each LaTeX run to see if various intermediate files change?). This switch from automatically choosing the "LaTeX" option to choosing "View" no longer works using `--output-directory` as described. I must now press <kbd>C-c C-c</kbd> and type "View" manually.

Does anyone know how I can tell AUCTeX that the output files are in "./output" and to compare to them when checking whether it is "time to View" rather than "time to LaTeX"?

Comment: Maybe via `TeX-check-path` variable...

Comment: @PolGab I tried adding "./output" and/or "./output/" to TeX-check-path but that didn't make any difference.

Comment: A workaround would be to use `C-c C-v`, which calls the `view` command regardless of what AUCTeX thinks about the 'readiness' of the `.pdf` or `.dvi` (etc.) file.

Comment: How did you add the options to Latex, Bibtex etc? I'd like to do that too.

Comment: @jon can you please write an answer?

Comment: @doed -- No problem.

Answer (score 1):

There is a relatively easy workaround if a better solution can't be found:

```
C-c C-v
```

calls `TeX-view`, which will open the associated `.pdf` or `.dvi` file (assuming there is one).  On my computer, `TeX-view` in fact calls `xdg-open`, but you can hardwire a particular viewer in you `.emacs` file if you like.